# Ошибка при использовании fragments в LibGDX с ARCore

Tags: android, libgdx, arcore

Делаю свой проект на LibGDX с дополненной реальностью (решил использовать ARCore). Нашел пример https://github.com/google/helloargdx - все работает но есть проблема. Именно в режиме дополненной реальности после нажатия на кнопку "домой" в приложение уже не вернуться, отрисовка не выполняется. Не могу разобраться в чем дело и как это решить?

по поводу комментария [Master Flomaster](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213710/master-flomaster).
Добавил вывод в лог: при нажатии кнопки "домой": вызывается MainActivity().onPause() ->
MainActivity().onStop() pre super и далее ничего.
Причем метод onStop() выглядит так:

```java
 protected void onStop() {
    Log.d("myLogs", "MainActivity().onStop() pre super");
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("myLogs", "MainActivity().onStop() post super");
 }
```

При возвращении в приложении onResume() не вызывается.
Вероятно проблема в super.onStop() - но в режиме без дополненной реальности все работает

Comment: Для начала стоит проверить вызывается ли метод resume() когда возвращаешься в игру

Comment: По ссылке есть примеры. С ними такая же проблема? Может быть ресурсы уничтожаются при потере фокуса. В общем без минимального кода можно долго гадать

Comment: Да, сам код есть по ссылке на github. Скачал проект, собрал через gradle в Android Studio. Код работает, зависание только в режиме дополненной реальности

Comment: В таком случае это проблемы библиотеки и надо изучить код. Не знаю будет ли кто-то этим заниматься или нет, но я бы поискал что-нибудь другое, учитывая что проект не обновляется уже 2 года